# Find pattern in text, Python

Tags: python, regex

right now I have `includePat = r'^#\s*include\s+"([^"]+)"'`
 
to match the pattern `#include "file.h"`

I'm having problems trying to correct it a little. What if the pattern is across two lines? As so..
`#include    \
            "file.h"`

How should I go about matching that?

EDIT:
Sorry guys, to be more clear, the string in the quotations could be anything, its not limited to file.h

Comment: how about: `read_file = " ".join(read_file.split())  if '#include "file.h"' in read_file: do something

Comment: Do you just want to run a binary check and see if the pattern exists in the file, or do you want to retrieve the C file name?

Comment: I just want to scan a file and search for the string `#include "file.h"` where `"file.h"` might be on a different line, and to then retrieve it... i would want to retrieve the entire string, including `#include` and `"file.h"` into a single string

Comment: Why not check if rightmost char == \ and then append the next line if so?  That would throw off your line #s, but...

Comment: @Shawn your regex does match the string if it has any \n char inbetween because `\s` would match any lind of space character including line breaks. I don't know what actually you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Building on @AvinashRaj's note and your deleted message below, I think your problem is actually the fact that you're iterating over each line in the file, then checking to see if that line contains a pattern that may span multiple lines. Either read the whole file into memory, or stream it in multiline chunks so you can find your matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to get rid of the white space and simply want to match it, what you have is pretty close.

This will match `#include` plus any following white space including new lines, and the following word in quotation marks

```
(#include\s+)"([^"]+)"
```

[Example](http://regexr.com/3bcc2)

Comment: This actually seems good, I'm not sure if getting rid of white space is necessary I will try it out... How would you get rid of the whitespace if need be?

Comment: the site for ur example got me answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
import re
import sys

includePat = re.compile(r'''
    (?xm)        # verbose, multiline
    ^\s*         # beginning of line, optional WS
    \#\s*        # hash, optional WS
    include      # include, naturally
    (?:\s*\\\n)* # any number of line continuations
    \s*"(.*?)"   # non-greedy string match -- .*?
''')

for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(filename) as fp:
        lines = fp.read();
    for include in includePat.findall(lines):
        print filename, include
```

One important bit is `(?:\s*\\\n)*`. The `\s*` is optional whitespace. The `\\` matches the C line continuation character. The `\n` matches the newline that must immediately follow the line continuation character. \

Another important aspect is that you have to match the entire file. With a single regular expression, you can't match each line independently in a loop -- you have to read the entire file into one buffer.